# Matrix multiplication in R – arguments are non-conformable, but should be

Tags: r, matrix, boolean, linear-algebra

I'm working on a boolean network representation of a genetic regulatory network. Below is a simplified version of the code with minimal genes, for debugging purposes. I first create matrixes representing regulatory relationships between genes in the network, and for regulatory states associated with four distinct cell types.

As for the part that isn't working... At each iteration, the evolve function assigns a new state (0 for "off" or 1 for "on") to each gene depending on the status of upstream regulators. This requires matrix multiplication of the vector of gene states with the matrix of regulatory interactions.

The goal of this code is to count how many times the regulatory network stabilizes with one of four known configurations, associated with distinct cell types, after iterating 10,000 times with randomly generated initial ON/OFF states for these genes.

Please help me figure out why this matrix multiplication is not working. I'm being told the arguments are nonconformable, but the vector and matrix meet the requirements for matrix multiplication (# of rows in left vector is equal to #columns in the right matrix, and R should be able to do matrix multiplication between a matrix and vector)

```
library(prodlim)    
genes <- c("SHR", "SCR", "JKD")
N <- length(genes)

gene_adjacency_matrix <- matrix(nrow=N, ncol=N)
gene_adjacency_matrix[,] <- 0
rownames(gene_adjacency_matrix) <- genes
colnames(gene_adjacency_matrix) <- genes

gene_adjacency_matrix["SHR", "SCR"] <- 1
gene_adjacency_matrix["SCR", "SCR"] <- 1
gene_adjacency_matrix["JKD", "SCR"] <- 1

num_cell_types <- 4
fixed_points_matrix <- matrix(nrow=num_cell_types, ncol=N)
fixed_points_matrix[,] <- 0
colnames(fixed_points_matrix) <- genes

fixed_points_matrix[1,"SHR"] <- 1
fixed_points_matrix[1,"SCR"] <- 1
fixed_points_matrix[1,"JKD"] <- 1
fixed_points_matrix[2,"SHR"] <- 1
fixed_points_matrix[2,"SCR"] <- 0
fixed_points_matrix[2,"JKD"] <- 0
fixed_points_matrix[3,"SHR"] <- 1
fixed_points_matrix[3,"SCR"] <- 0
fixed_points_matrix[3,"JKD"] <- 1
fixed_points_matrix[4,"SHR"] <- 0
fixed_points_matrix[4,"SCR"] <- 0
fixed_points_matrix[4,"JKD"] <- 0

fixation_counter <- vector(length=num_cell_types, mode="integer")
fixation_counter[] <- 0

evolve <- function(state) {
  result <- state %*% gene_adjacency_matrix 
  result[result > 0] <- 1
  result[result == 0] <- state[result == 0]
  result[result < 0] <- 0
  return(result)    
}

nsim <- 10000
for(i in 1:nsim) {
  state <- N; sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=N)
  state_previous <- state
  state <- evolve(state)
  if(state == state_previous) {quit}
  matched_cell_state <- row.match(state, fixed_points_matrix)
  fixation_counter[matched_cell_state] <- (fixation_counter[matched_cell_state] + 1)
  print(fixation_counter)
}

Error in state %*% gene_adjacency_matrix : non-conformable arguments
> state
[1] 3
> state <- N; sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=N)
[1] 0 1 1
> gene_adjacency_matrix
    SHR SCR JKD
SHR   0   1   0
SCR   0   1   0
JKD   0   1   0
```

Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Your code says `state <- N; sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=N)`  so state will be a single number.  Did you want `state <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=N)`

Comment: @G5W Both ways of assigning state appear to give the same result – a randomized vector of N values of 0 or 1. What's the difference?